# Get number of row records

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to append data using word as front-end userform and export the data to specific csv file when submit button is clicked.

While firstly I need to know which row I should append the data. Here is the following code and I got error message for `nrow = rng1.UsedRange.Rows.Count` lines

```
'Reference - Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object library 12

'Word
Global objDoc As word.Document
Global docName As String
Global docPath As String
Global docFullName As String

'Workbook
Global objWb As Excel.Workbook
Global objWs As Excel.Worksheet
Global rng1 As Range
Global nrow As Integer
'Global objWord As word.Application

Public Sub Initial_Global()
    'Word
    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    docName = objDoc.Name
    docPath = objDoc.Path
    docFullName = objDoc.FullName

    'Excel
    Set objWb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\1502911\Desktop\Database1.csv")
    Set objWs = objWb.Worksheets("Database1")
    Set rng1 = objWs.Range("A1")
    nrow = rng1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    MsgBox nrow
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want nrow to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nrow = rng1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

this means:

```
Worksheets("Database1").Range("A1").UsedRange.Rows.Count 'wrong
```

of course it will return error, because you asking the used range of the range "A1"

must be like this:

```
Worksheets("Database1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

so in your code, if you required to count only rows in used range of the column "A" must be the next:

```
nrow = objWs.UsedRange.Columns(1).Rows.Count
```

but be carefull with this method of the getting the last row in sheet, the problem will apear when the used range will not start from the first row, e.g. if the first row will be empty then you will recieve count less then expected. in this case use this method:

```
nrow = objWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

also can be the problem, when e.g. count of the used cells in column "A" less by the some reason than count of the used cells in Columns "B" or "D " etc. but you need to get the last non-used row, in this case you need this method:

```
Dim ocell As Range
For Each ocell In objWs.UsedRange
    nrow = ocell.Row
Next
MsgBox nrow
```